# Crashlytics in not showing up the crash reports

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, firebase, crashlytics

I have implemented a Firebase crashlytics in my project, and also I have configured the firebase account with my project. But when I do a crash with the help of `Crashlytics.sharedInstance().crash()` I will get crash crash report perfectly. But if I do a crash with any other method, it is not showing up the crash report. But some crashes are showing in the dSYMs tab in crashlytics and it is not formatted correctly. I have downloaded the dSYM file from the iTunes store and uploaded to Crashlytics through terminal. But Still I am getting the crashes in the dSYMs tab and not formatted correctly.

[image]

This is How I am getting crash report in dSYMs tab in Crashlytics.

Does anybody know what I am doing wrong here?

I could able to implement it in my Swift project and it correctly decrypted the errors and displayed correctly. But when I implemented it into my Objective-C project, I am not getting the correct decrypted report.

Comment: Did you checked https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-deobfuscated-reports?platform=ios&authuser=0 to find the one? Also did you enabled bit code?

Comment: Yes, I have checked and enabled bit code true.

Answer (score 1):

When having "optional" missing dSYMs, those are usually related to .frameworks or other third party library being used. If you only have these kinds of missing dSYMs, the dashboardwill show the crash report, but the frames related to those dSYMs won't be symbolized.

DSYMs marked as "required" are related to your main app, when those are missing, the dashboard won't show the crash report.

Usually, when using a .framework, the dSYMs files should also be available, but if not, you'd probably need to get them from the framework owners.

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate Gerardo's answer further, please refer to your Xcode Organizer. There goes a list of your app published with different version. Download the dSYM
reports first and hence follows the procedures given from Google and submit those dSYM to firebase

Make sure you have already installed the latest version of **FirebaseCrashlytics** via Cocoapods and proper app profile at your Firebase Console.

[https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-deobfuscated-reports#upload-dsyms](http://%20%20%20%20https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-deobfuscated-reports#upload-dsyms)